# Discord.py Cog on load listener

Tags: python, events, discord.py

I am working on my discord bot and have multiple cogs each with their own functions and commands. I have been looking for a way to for it to send a message that states it loaded successfully and a list of the commands added. I currently have them all with the on_ready() listener, but that only seems to run when the bot initializes and not when the cog is loaded. Is there any event that would trigger once the cog is loaded or how would I go about making one?

Comment: The `__init__` or `__new__`method...?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```py
cogs = {"cogs.CommandErrorHandler",
            "cogs.Music",
            "cogs.Fun",
            "cogs.OwnerOnly",
            "cogs.Info",
            "cogs.Moderation",
            "cogs.Polls",
            "cogs.Soundboard",
            "cogs.Statcord",
            "jishaku"
            }

for cog in cogs:
    try:
        client.load_extension(cog)
    except discord.ext.commands.ExtensionError as error:
        print(f"{cog} could not be loaded.")
    else:
        print(f"{cog} has been loaded.")
```